# navigator.geolocation.watchPosition - Opera browser

Tags: geolocation, opera, navigator

I'm trying to retrieve the geolocation on Opera browser, but I got no response or a timeout.

I have use the following:

```
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition


navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {alert('Got it');}, failure => {alert('Failed');},{ maximumAge: 30000, timeout: 30000, enableHighAccuracy: true });
```

I have try the following lib: https://github.com/gregsramblings/getAccurateCurrentPosition

I even use a timeout of 30 seconds (which is way too much).

But no way, I can't find a way to get my location back.

PS: it works everywhere else Windows / Mac / Android  / iPhone !

If you have any idea ?

Comment: May I know which opera version are you using?

Comment: The very last, downloaded yesterday.So it is 69.0.3686.95